# Should I response an HTTP 5xx or 4xx for business logic errors?

Tags: .net, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

If I would need to make some validations on my business logic what status code would you recommend me?

(e.g) I have to validate if the username is previously registered.

I'd use a

> 400 Bad Request

or

> 409 Conflict

but I'm not really sure if it's the best option.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTTP specification: the `5xx` series of response codes should be used in case of "internal server error" - which is to say that something bad happened in the webserver that is the fault of the developer (or the sysadmin - something of that nature) and not the end-user of the webservice.

`4xx` means "something is wrong with the data that was sent to the server", for example `404` is for a resource that the client requested that doesn't exist and `400` is for generic "bad request" (e.g. an XML request was missing a required element, for example).

Your example of returning HTTP `409 Conflict` for "username is already registered" seems fine, though strictly speaking this should only be used when the request is on a specific entity. A 409 response wouldn't be appropriate when the request path does not uniquely identify a specific resource.